# Secret scheduled tasks in windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, task-scheduler

I'm taking care of the company's website for a while. The guy who was doing so before me was fired because reasons. So for the past 3 months I've been keeping it up to date and adding/deleting stuff. Not a big deal, I know a bit of PHP so it is not a problem.

However, the problem is not there.

The manager told me as soon as I took the charge that there was "magic" going on behind the server. Every night, there are a few scripts written in PHP that update our website and the database. Well, I know **which** scripts are being executed, and **where** they are; but I can't find **why** they are being executed.

The scripts are located in the `controllers/tasks` folder inside our server, but there's nothing in the task scheduler.

How can I find out **how** are these tasks being programmed, and if I can change their frequency? Thanks before hand.

**DATA**
Windows Server 2003
running WAMP 2.1, which includes

- Apache 2.2.11
- MySQL 5.1
- PHP 5.3

PS. Excuse my poor english.

Comment: Are they running under "AT" ?

Comment: Are you sure they're being run as scheduled tasks?  They could be services or scripts, or processes launched by something in the WAMP software on a regular schedule.  Using scheduled tasks is far from the only way to run something on a schedule in Windows.

Comment: Are you sure the tasks can only be triggered locally?  Is some other machine on your network is running cron or something and using curl to trigger these tasks?  Do you see any requests in your log files that correspond with the time the tasks are being triggered?

Comment: Sorry I'm late. I'm currently checking if there is another machine executing them, just as @Zoredache suggested. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to setup a scheduled task to output all the running tasks during the time period when the other task runs.

Here is a quick example command (could be built more robust if run over time) that could be scheduled through the task scheduler.

```
tasklist >> c:\temp\taskoutput.txt
```

Depending on how long the other task runs, you could schedule this command for every hour and check it in the morning for suspect processes.

Comment: That looks pausible. I'll do it today and inform about the results tomorrow in the morning. Thanks a lot!